# JSON stringify not working over the IIS call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, jquery

in my asp.net MVC 3 application.

follwoing ajax call working well on my developement machine, but when i publish the application on IIS server it fails or object always sends null value to save function.

```
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: '../MyPath/save',
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({'Model': object}),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
                return true;
            }
          });

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(SampleModel Model) 
           * Model values always null over IIS *
    { 

    }
```

i have even tried to use @url.action() and even tried in another broweser but still same problem persist.

anyone has any idea why this is not working on IIS call.?

please suggest. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `jQuery.parseJSON()`

```
     $.ajax({
        url: '../MyPath/save',
        type: 'POST', 
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: jQuery.parseJSON({'Model': object}),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        }
     });
```

from the docs:

```
Passing in a malformed JSON string may result in an exception being thrown. 
For example, the following are all malformed JSON strings:
```

- `{test: 1}` (*test does not have double quotes around it*).
- `{'test': 1}` (*'test' is using single quotes instead of double quotes*).

[**More info**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: thanks jai..i have tried this but still facing same problem..plz suggest an yother way to do this.i am pulling my hair since 1 day..still not getting this issue clear..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript will result in double wrapping your model, the binding process will be looking for `Model` property in the `SampleModel` class. To bind directly it should rather be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../MyPath/save',
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(object),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks..but i have tried this also..not working.plz suggest another way..still sending null values..

Comment: @user1799982 Show us your JavaScript object and SampleModel class